# Return Mono.empty() from mono{} coroutine scope

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor

```
mono {
  val abc: Int? = getSomeValue().awaitSingleOrNull

  abc
}
```

What will the above block return if abc is null and how to return Mono.empty() if abc is null ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look closely at `mono` function signature you see that:

- It allows the lambda/closure to return a null value: `block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T?`
- It returns a non-nullable Mono : `Mono<T>` (its expected, as Mono does not support null values)

The documentation states:

> If the result of block is null, MonoSink.success is invoked without a value.

That may not be very clear as an explanation, but it means that in case of null value, a Mono which only send completion signal will be returned. This is the definition of an empty Mono.

We can test it with the simple program:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.reactor.mono
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono

fun main() {

    var empty : Mono<String> = mono { null }

    empty.defaultIfEmpty("EMPTY !")
         .block()
        ?.let(::println)
}
```

It prints `EMPTY !`, which shows well that the null value has been treated as "no value", and produced an empty Mono.

Answer (score 2):

`Mono.empty()` equals to

```
mono {
    // .. codes
    
    null // return
}
```

If `mono { null }` or `flux { null }` will be empty event. If you use code before `null` they will be run, just not emit anything.

```kotlin
val x: Mono<Void> = mono {
    // your code will be executed
    null
}
```